# website quits before I can parse anything

Tags: python, selenium

**Background:**

Cannot parse all the `li`'s within the `<ul class="cmn-list">` using selenium.

**Code:**

```
url= "https://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/international?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

preferences = {"safebrowsing.enabled": "false"}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe',  chrome_options=chrome_options)


print(url)
browser.get(url)
delay = 20 # seconds


try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay)
except:
    pass


html_list = browser.find_element_by_class_name("cmn-list")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for item in items:
    text = item.text
    print(text)
```

**Question:**

How can I parse the rows `li`s in the [link](https://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/international?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60) `<ul class="cmn-list">` with selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple `ul` tags with the same `class_name`. Using `browser.find_element_by_class_name('cmn-list')` will only select the first `ul` tag with this `class_name`, not the `ul` tag that you want. In order to get the `ul` tag that you want, I recommend you to use `xpaths`. Here is the full code to do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def printDetails(items, sponsored):
    if sponsored == True:
        print('-'*120)
        print("Sponsored")
    else:
        print('-' * 120)
        print("Others")

    for item in items:
        link = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')
        title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').text
        company = item.find_element_by_class_name('job-title').find_element_by_xpath('.//p').text
        date_time = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="job-post-time ng-binding"]').text.split("\n")

        datee = date_time[0]
        timee = date_time[1]

        print('-' * 120)
        print(f"Job Title = {title}")
        print(f"Link = {link}")
        print(f"Company = {company}")
        print(f"Date = {datee}")
        print(f"Time = {timee}")

url= "https://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/international?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

preferences = {"safebrowsing.enabled": "false"}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',  options=chrome_options)


print(url)
browser.get(url)
delay = 20 # seconds


try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay)
except:
    pass

time.sleep(3)

sponsored = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mid-wrapper"]/div/section[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul')
sponsored_items = sponsored.find_elements_by_class_name('ng-scope')
html_list = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mid-wrapper"]/div/section[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/ul')
items = html_list.find_elements_by_class_name('ng-scope')
printDetails(sponsored_items, sponsored = True)
printDetails(items, sponsored = False)
browser.close()
```

Output:

```
https://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/international?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sponsored
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Native-speaking English Teacher | Taiwan (NT$620 - NT$660 per hour)
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/native-speaking-english-teacher-nst?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = HESS International Educational Group
Date = Apr. 20, 2020
Time = 07:39 pm PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Others
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = University Teaching in Japan! – Tokyo, Kanagawa, Chiba, Saitama, and Aichi
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/university-teaching-in-japan---tokyo-kanagawa-37?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Westgate Corporation
Date = Oct. 23, 2020
Time = 09:22 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Elementary/Secondary School Teaching in Japan! - Tokyo, Kanagawa, and Aichi
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/elementarysecondary-school-teaching-in-japan-8?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Westgate Corporation
Date = Oct. 23, 2020
Time = 09:22 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Seeking online English Tutor - Up to $26USD/h - Work from home! Choose your own hours!
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/seeking-online-english-tutor---up-to-26usdh--?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Magic Ears
Date = Oct. 23, 2020
Time = 09:20 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = English Language Lectutrer in Oman for SY 2020
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/english-language-lectutrer-in-oman-for-sy-202?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = TATI Oman
Date = Oct. 22, 2020
Time = 11:06 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = ⭐$2000/month, 3-5 hrs per day⭐, Teach English Online with GOGOKID!
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/2000month-3-5-hrs-per-day-teach-english-onlin?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = GOGOKID
Date = Oct. 22, 2020
Time = 11:06 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = [Bachelor's Required]Part-Time Online ESL Teacher - Work from home - Flexible Job!
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/bachelors-requiredpart-time-online-esl-teache?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Magic Ears
Date = Oct. 22, 2020
Time = 11:05 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = ★★★TRAVEL ABROAD & TEACH IN THAILAND with BFITS THAILAND (Term 2 November 2020)★★★
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/travel-abroad-teach-in-thailand-with-bfits-th-22?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = BFITS Thailand
Date = Oct. 22, 2020
Time = 11:05 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Full-time In-house Academic Editor Wanted in Taipei, Taiwan
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/full-time-in-house-academic-editor-wanted-in-6?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Wallace Academic Editing
Date = Oct. 21, 2020
Time = 01:44 pm PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Online English Tutor
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/online-english-tutor?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Panda ABC
Date = Oct. 21, 2020
Time = 01:41 pm PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Native Speaker Teacher - Changhua, Taiwan
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/native-speaker-teacher?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Leader Language Schools
Date = Oct. 21, 2020
Time = 01:24 pm PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Teachers Needed in Fiji - Pacific American School
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/fiji-pacific-american-school?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Pacific American School
Date = Oct. 21, 2020
Time = 10:44 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Online ESL tutor wanted! Teach Korean students online. (CNK English)
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/online-esl-tutor-wanted-teach-korean-students-1?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = CNK English
Date = Oct. 20, 2020
Time = 08:15 pm PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Primary Section (Class Teacher for grades 2-3) - Dushanbe, Tajikistan
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/primary-section-class-teacher-for-grades-2-3?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Dushanbe International School
Date = Oct. 20, 2020
Time = 08:42 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Native English Teacher needed for private classes - Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia)
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/english-teacher-needed-for-private-classes-ku?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = BLC
Date = Oct. 20, 2020
Time = 08:40 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = English Language Center Lecturer - Taiwan
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/english-language-center-lecturer?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Tunghai University
Date = Oct. 20, 2020
Time = 08:39 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = 【⭐GOGOKID offers candidate incentive again⭐】Teach English Online
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/extra-bonus-30-for-on-boardteach-english-onli?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = GOGOKID
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 08:46 pm PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Looking for Online ESL Teacher!!!
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/looking-for-online-esl-teacher-1?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = First Future
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:23 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Online English Teacher
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/online-english-teacher-7?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Whales English
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:23 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title =   Teach English in Poland with English Wizards!  
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/teach-english-in-poland-with-english-wizards?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = English Wizards
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:22 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = US Certified Science Teacher - Tirane, Albania
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/us-certified-science-teacher?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Albanian International School
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:22 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Fantastic teaching jobs around Taiwan, hiring single and couples ASAP
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/fantastic-teaching-jobs-around-taiwan-hiring?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = ESLJOBTAIWAN
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:21 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title =    Become a Mentor for Language Learners on Ski Camps - Free Hotel Stays in Europe   
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/become-a-mentor-for-language-learners-on-ski?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Angloville
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:19 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = 【⭐Extra Bonus-First come first served】Online English Tutor-Earn up to $25/hr
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/extra-bonus-first-come-first-servedonline-eng?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = GOGOKID
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:19 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = University Teaching in Japan! – Tokyo, Kanagawa, Chiba, Saitama, and Aichi
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/university-teaching-in-japan---tokyo-kanagawa-36?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Westgate Corporation
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:18 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Elementary/Secondary School Teaching in Japan! - Tokyo, Kanagawa, and Aichi
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/elementarysecondary-school-teaching-in-japan-7?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Westgate Corporation
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:18 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Online ESL Tutor - No minimum teaching requirements - $26/hr part-time job
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/online-esl-tutor---no-minimum-teaching-requir?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Magic Ears
Date = Oct. 19, 2020
Time = 09:17 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title =  SUNNY SPAIN, MARVELOUS MADRID & an EXCITING, LOVELY LIFE with the Canterbury English TEFL & Madrid Lifestyle (for TEFL holders) Programs&Guaranteed Teaching Job for all students WITH US (that's the key), which starts during the Course! 
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/128156128155128153-sunny-spain-marvelous-madr-30?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Canterbury English
Date = Oct. 18, 2020
Time = 09:36 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Math Teacher - Hargeisa, Somaliland
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/math-teacher-2?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Abaarso School of Science & Technology
Date = Oct. 17, 2020
Time = 10:56 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Math/English Teacher - Hargeisa, Somaliland
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/mathenglish-teacher?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Barwaaqo Univeristy
Date = Oct. 17, 2020
Time = 10:46 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = TAIWAN! Teach English at schools throughout the beautiful island of TAIWAN - $2,200 USD per month. Taipei, Tainan, Kaohsiung, Taichung, Keelung, PingDong. Summer 2020 graduates welcome.
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/taiwan-teach-english-at-schools-throughout-th-35?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Arun Language Training & Recruitment Ltd
Date = Oct. 17, 2020
Time = 10:18 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Online Technical Copywriter
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/technical-copywriter?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Lingvoexpert
Date = Oct. 16, 2020
Time = 10:21 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = ★★★LIVE ABROAD & TEACH IN THAILAND with BFITS THAILAND (Term 2 November 2020)★★★
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/live-abroad-teach-in-thailand-with-bfits-thai-3?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = BFITS Thailand
Date = Oct. 16, 2020
Time = 10:18 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = US $2500-5000/M + PU Letter+ Teach in China + International & Public School + Training Center + IB + AP + A-level + Social Science, Math, Physics, Chemistry + All Regular Subjects
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/apiba-levelmathsciencechemistryphysicscompute?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Can-Achieve Global Talent Inc.
Date = Jul. 21, 2020
Time = 07:13 pm PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Head of Primary and Head of Secondary required ASAP - Iraq- Erbil
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/head-of-primary-and-head-of-secondary-require?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = British International School/Iraq-Kurdistan- Erbil
Date = Oct. 15, 2020
Time = 09:35 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Full Time English Teacher in Ehime, JAPAN
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/full-time-english-teacher-in-ehime-japan?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Amic International Inc.
Date = Oct. 15, 2020
Time = 09:34 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = 【⭐Dave's Recommendation】Online English Tutor-Earn up to $25/hr
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/daves-recommendationonline-english-tutor-earn?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = GOGOKID
Date = Oct. 15, 2020
Time = 09:32 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Teaching English with Magic Ears! - Work from home - Uni students are also acceptable!
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/teaching-english-with-magic-ears---work-from?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Magic Ears
Date = Oct. 15, 2020
Time = 09:30 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Teach in Taiwan
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/teach-in-taiwan-1?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Neurolink English Academy
Date = Oct. 14, 2020
Time = 09:29 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Japan: Teaching English to children!
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/japan-teaching-english-to-children?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Tamaki TEFL Recruitment (TTR)
Date = Oct. 14, 2020
Time = 09:26 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = ESL Instructors Needed for Community Education Courses Baghdad, Iraq
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/esl-instructors-needed-for-community-educatio?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = English Language Academy
Date = Oct. 14, 2020
Time = 09:25 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Online English Teacher - Up to $26/hr - With no minimum teaching requirements!
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/online-english-teacher---up-to-26hr---with-no?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Magic Ears
Date = Oct. 14, 2020
Time = 09:23 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Worldwide ESL/EFL Projects for the U.S. Department of State in 2021/2022
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/worldwide-eslefl-projects-for-the-us-departme-13?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = U.S. Department of State English Language Programs
Date = Oct. 13, 2020
Time = 01:38 pm PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Biggest ESL School in Vietnam - NOW Hiring Teachers
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/biggest-esl-school-in-vietnam---now-hiring-te-7?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = APAX English
Date = Oct. 13, 2020
Time = 10:13 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = EXPERIENCED EFL TEACHER NEEDED AT NORTHSTAR COLLEGE, Hargeisa, Somaliland
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/experienced-efl-teacher-needed-at-northstar-c?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Northstar College
Date = Oct. 13, 2020
Time = 10:12 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = Full time English Teacher - Kanazawa, Japan
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/full-time-english-teacher-8?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Bartolo English
Date = Oct. 13, 2020
Time = 09:09 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = A good choice for ESL teachers! Teaching English online for Chinese kids - Earn up to $26/hr
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/a-good-choice-for-esl-teachers-teaching-engli?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Magic Ears
Date = Oct. 13, 2020
Time = 09:07 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = ⭐Attention⭐Online Teaching Position offers up to $25/hr
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/online-english-tutor-earn-up-to-25hr?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = GOGOKID
Date = Oct. 13, 2020
Time = 09:06 am PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Title = ⭐⭐⭐⭐ESL Teaching Positions Available in Taiwan NOW ⭐⭐⭐⭐
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/esl-teaching-positions-available-in-taiwan-no-6?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Teach Taiwan
Date = Oct. 12, 2020
Time = 11:38 pm PST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...

Job Title = Work in Japan
Link = https://www.eslcafe.com/postajob-detail/work-in-japan?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60
Company = Omni International
Date = Oct. 08, 2020
Time = 10:21 am PST
```

Comment: that's great! one additional, how can I extract the associated links that point to each advert?

Answer (score 0):

The answer above waits 3 seconds assuming your internet will take less than 3 seconds to load, but if you'd like to wait until there is a certain text in your page you can do:

```
url= "https://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/international?koreasearch=&koreapageno=&koreapagesize=&chinasearch=&chinapageno=&chinapagesize=&internationalsearch=&internationalpageno=1&internationalpagesize=60"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

preferences = {"safebrowsing.enabled": "false"}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe',  chrome_options=chrome_options)


print(url)
browser.get(url)

displayTimer = 0
wanted_Phrase = "li" # You should put some text that is only on the page when it has loaded.
while wanted_Phrase not in browser.page_source:
    sleep(1)
    displayTimer += 1
    print("[{}] Seconds waited for page".format(displayTimer))


html_list = browser.find_element_by_class_name("cmn-list")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for item in items:
    text = item.text
    print(text)
```